# jquery autocomplete plugin didn't work perfectly with json

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-autocomplete

i write a code for autocomplete a textbox using jquery autocomplete plugin..... but it cann't working properly

here is html

```
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    <input class="searchBox" id="isearch" name="isearch" value="" type="text" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hsearch" id="hsearch" />
```

and javascript

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#isearch").autocomplete(
     "search.php", 

      {
            select: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#isearch").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#hsearch").val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#isearch").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    }
});
    });
```

the PHP code is

```
    <?php
       include 'config.php';

       $q=$_GET['q']; 
       $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
       $sql="SELECT emp_id,name FROM f_name WHERE name LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY name";
       $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
       $results = array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $results[] = array('value' => $row['emp_id'],'label' => $row['name']);
}
echo json_encode($results);

    ?>
```

and json value that return in textbox is

```
   [
     {"value":"2","label":"AAA ZZZ"},
     {"value":"3","label":"Roger Fedrer"},
     {"value":"1","label":"Php Admin"}
   ]
```

i want that textbox only show "label" and "value" should store in hidden-field

Comment: There are several autocomplete plugins please give a link to the one that you are using

Comment: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Comment: any other solution related to jquery and json will be highly appreciated

Comment: I usually use http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html

Comment: Are you trying to do an ajax-based autocomplete?

Comment: yes but cann't figure out how to do that........ i think problem is in javascript

Comment: does it need to be cross-browser? You can just use datalist in html5 to make it more simpler. You can check out datalist support here http://wufoo.com/html5/ And here's a tutorial on using datalist: http://goo.gl/6whku

Comment: As you are not using multiple auto complete values then you can use http://tomcoote.co.uk/code-bank/jquery-json-suggestsearch-box/ or the newer version http://tomcoote.co.uk/javascript/jquery-json-suggestsearch-box-v2/

Comment: @ Kyoka Suigetsu didn't work in chrome

Comment: Does your code works when you remove `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @Imdad yes it work without   event.preventDefault();

Comment: then try to place  it before `return false;` BTW I do not understand the reason you are preventing default

Comment: Normally `return false` both prevents default and stops propagation... so that's redundant.  Could stopping the propagation (via `return false`) be causing your problem?

Comment: isn't it because you didn't write "source" before "search.php"?